# print_any for F# 2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#

I am upgrading an old version 1.0 F# project to 2.0 using visual studio 2010. So many changes.

I can't seem to find the print_any command that was littered all over the place in the old books and samples.

I have installed powerpack but can't find it there either.

Any idea where i can find this command.

PS: I know I can easily implement it myself but was curious where this is now.

Comment: I assume you know about `printfn "%A" anything`?

Comment: For updating old code, see also this description of many library/naming/etc changes in Beta1: http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2009/05/20/detailed-release-notes-for-the-f-may-2009-ctp-update-and-visual-studio-2010-beta1-releases.aspx

Comment: @Benjol: I was just about to do a search replace with printfn
@Brian: I did come across it and searched for print_any without any success. I guess I should stop being lazy and read the whole thing as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The libraries for F# 2.0 underwent a redesign and clean up. I think think `print_any` was removed for two specific reasons:

- It was a goal to removed all of the under scores from F# function names (accept for the under scores in OCaml compatibility library, which is shipped with the powerpack).
- Reduce the number of similar functions, to reduce the api surface area and to remove some of the problems of having two ways of achieving the same thing.

So, since it's easy to replace `print_any` with `printfn "%A"` it was removed.